# Find expression for the sum of the series $\sum (-1)^{(n-1)}nx^{(2n)}$ on the interval of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$\sum (-1)^{(n-1)}nx^{(2n)}$

I found the interval of convergence to be (-1 < x < 1).
According to the book my next step would be to use a know Maclaurin serie and then probably differentiate my way to the sum of expression.

But as I got started.. could I not just do it like this:

f(x) = $\sum (-1)^{(n-1)}nx^{(2n)}$ on (-1 < x < 1)$.

Known Maclaurin series: $$\sum(-1)^{(n-1)}\frac{x^{(n)}}{n} = \ln(1+x)$$

-->

$$\frac{f(x)}{x^n*n^2} = \ln(1+x)$$

-->
$$f(x) = \ln(1+x)*x^n*n^2$$

Could it be that simple?

Comment: I tried to format your question MathJax but could not decipher it.

Comment: I hope I have not changed the meaning when putting this into readable format...

Answer (score 0):

You have done something wrong, because

$$\sum (-1)^{(n-1)}nx^{(2n)} = \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Comment: Got to your answer. Thanks for the hint, sorry for the formatting..